# Django models Integrity error

Tags: django, django-models, relationship, integrity

```
class Subscribers(User):
    date = models.DateField()
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

class Tour(models.Model):
    """ This is not the id is a User object
    """
    owner_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    location = models.ManyToManyField(Location)
    subscribers = models.ManyToManyField(Subscribers, related_name="sub")
```

I am trying to test a method using:

```
def test_get_subsribers(self):
    user1= User.objects.create_user('Maria','j@j.com','j1')
    user4= User.objects.create_user('Giannis','m@m.com','m1')
    sub= Subscribers()
    sub.user = user4
    tour = Tour()
    tour.owner_id = user1
    tour.name = "Open Day"
    tour.subscribers.add(sub)
    self.assertEqual(get_subscribers("Open Day").count(),0)
```

But what I get is an error:

```
IntegrityError: insert or update on table "tour_tour_subscribers" violates foreign key constraint "tour_tour_subscribers_subscribers_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (subscribers_id)=(10) is not present in table "tour_subscribers".
```

I am new in Django and I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to add non-saved Subscriber to Tour.

You need to call `sub.save()` before `tour.subscribers.add(sub)`

The `tour` must also be saved before adding `sub`.

The reason for this is the additional table that handles many to many relations ([see docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#id1)). This table stores two Foreign keys - one for `Tour` and one for `Subscribers`. To save a row into this table both Tour and Subscriber should exist in database

Comment: What if I want to add another subscriber to the tour?